# basename and dirname not working in sendFile

Tags: node.js, express, path

I have a file at '/x/y/file.pdf' and I want to send it to my browser to be opened. Im using nodejs Express as my server-side and the file is sent using `sendFile()`. using `path.relative()` I can get the relative path based on app.js path, which turns out to be '../../x/y/file.pdf'. Now if I hard code these paths such as:

```
res.sendFile('file.pdf',{'root':'../../x/y/'})
```

things work as expected and the pdf opens in the browser. But we know hardcoding is not the way so if I try:

```
var relPath = path.relative(__dirname,path.dirname('/x/y/file.pdf'));
res.sendFile(path.basename('/x/y/file.pdf'),'root':relPath});
```

I get an ENOENT error. Why is this?

Comment: You got error because sendFile does not find file at path

Answer (score 0):

If your File in Public folder in root directory then you can use below mentioned code

```
  const options = {
    root: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
  }

  var fileName = "file.pdf"
  res.sendFile(fileName, options, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      next(err)
    } else {
      console.log('Sent:', fileName)
    }
  })
})
```

if you have like this folder structure

```
/src
├── config/
│   ├── db.conf.js
├── database/
│   ├── Redis.database.js
│   ├── Mongo.database.js
│   ├── init.js
├── routes/
│   ├── App.routes.js
│   ├── Auth.routes.js
│   ├── Dashboard.routes.js
├── files/
│   ├── folder1
│       ├──file1.txt
│       ├──file2.pdf
```

then in root option you can pass like this and you want to send file1.txt then,

```
root: path.join(__dirname, 'files',"folder1")
```

and in sendFile pass file name 'file1.txt'